# Get content between a pair of HTML tags using Bash

Tags: html, bash

I need to get the HTML contents between a pair of given tags using a bash script.
As an example, having the HTML code below:

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
 text
  <div>
  text2
    <div>
        text3
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Using the bash command/script, given the *body* tag, we would get:

```
 text
  <div>
  text2
    <div>
    text3
    </div>
  </div>
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

plain text processing is not good for html/xml parsing. I hope this could give you some idea:

```
kent$  xmllint --xpath "//body" f.html 
<body>
 text
  <div>
  text2
    <div>
        text3
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Note that HTML often isn't valid XML. If this is the case, you can use tools like [Beautiful Soup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/) or jtidy to clean the HTML.

Comment: Nice; to extract only the *content* of the body element as X[HT]ML, use `xmllint --xpath '//body/node()' f.html`.

Comment: hi this is exactly what i was looking for, can you help me -- since there could be many `<div>`'s, how to specify a tag with a class attribute, for example `<div class="row content-wrapper"> give me this content and this tag in a file<\div>` - and write it to `a newfile withOrignalNameUpdate.nextExtension` i tried this `--output file` but did not know how to get the original file name, can you also update this as file we can run

Comment: xmllint doesn't seem to be able to interpolate into variables either. Doesn't seem like a good option.

Comment: @NorseGaud if I didn't understand your concern wrongly, the "variable" problem can be solved by shell command substitution or process substitution right? IMO, it's not the focus of this question.

Answer (score 16):

Using sed in shell/bash, so you needn't install something else.

```
tag=body
sed -n "/<$tag>/,/<\/$tag>/p" file
```

Comment: Nice, but the OP wanted to exclude the start and end tag; in the simplest case - assuming the tags are on a separate line each - you can pipe to `... | sed '1d;$d'`

Comment: I did on case by case, no need to guess what is not required.

Comment: This is nice solution, and actually the tag can be different, then we can extract section between any two tags, for example, ` sed -n "/<name>your_app_name/,/<\/application>/p" yourfile.xml` able to pull out section start from <name>your_app_name</name> line till </application> which is nearest the end of <application>...</application> section, the section pulled out is exactly app information

Comment: Please test it. It seems not working stable.

Answer (score 11):

Personally I find it very useful to use `hxselect` command (often with help of `hxclean`) from package html-xml-utils. The latter fixes (sometimes broken) HTML file to correct XML file and the first one allows to use CSS selectors to get the node(s) you need. With use of the `-c` option, it strips surrounding tags. All these commands work on stdin and stdout. So in your case you should execute:

```
$ hxselect -c body <<HTML
  <html>
  <head>
  </head>
  <body>
    text
    <div>
      text2
      <div>
        text3
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
  </html>
  HTML
```

to get what you need. Plain and simple.

Answer (score 7):

Forgetting Bash due it's limitation, you can use [nokogiri](http://nokogiri.org/) as command line util, as explained [here](http://robm.me.uk/ruby/2014/01/06/nokogiri-command-line.html).

Example:

```
curl -s http://example.com/ | nokogiri -e 'puts $_.search('\''a'\'')'
```

Answer (score 5):

Another option is  to use the multi-platform **`xidel`** utility ([home page on SourceForge](http://videlibri.sourceforge.net/xidel.html#downloads), [GitHub repository](https://github.com/benibela/xidel)), which can handle both XML and HTML:

```
xidel -s in.html -e '/html/body/node()' --printed-node-format=html
```

The above prints the resulting HTML with syntax highlighting (colored), and seemingly with an empty line after the `text` node.

If you want the text only, [Reino](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2703456/reino) points out that you can simplify to:

```
xidel -s in.html -e '/html/body/inner-html()'
```

Comment: Fantastic. Also available on AUR for Arch users.

Answer (score 1):

I just discovered a really nice Unix command line tool for this, [hq](https://github.com/coderobe/hq).

I use Arch-Linux where installing was simply `pacman -S hq`.

My problem was extracting json-ld from html headers, and with hq you just go

```bash
curl -sSL https://www.example.com | hq '[type="application/ld+json"]' text
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider using [beautifulspoon](https://github.com/gzttech/beautifulspoon).

Select the body tag from the above .html:

```
$ beautifulspoon example.html --select body
<body>
 text
 <div>
  text2
  <div>
   text3
  </div>
 </div>
</body>
```

And to unwrap the  tag:

```
$ beautifulspoon example.html --select body |beautifulspoon --select body --unwrap
text
<div>
 text2
 <div>
  text3
 </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

BASH is probably the wrong tool for this. Try a Python script using the powerful [Beautiful Soup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/) library instead.

It will be more work upfront but in the long run (here: after one hour), the time savings will make up for the additional effort.