# Using sed to replace pattern

Tags: bash, sed

How can i write bash script to do the below

1. search all files recursively within directory ending with html and htm.
2. using sed to search for `<body>` and delete all lines before this line including the `<body>` line
3. As well as searching for `</body>` and deleting all the lines after that including `<body>` line.
4. the change should not be on the same file but like index-temp.html.

I wrote the below but I cant get how can I change the whole block after and safe the change to another file and not on the same file. Do I have to use if?

```
#!/bin/bash
input=$1
find "$input" -type f -name "*.htm" -exec sed
```

Comment: There is no question and you probably mean `sed` instead of  `sid`.

Comment: Assuming your files are (reasonably-)valid HTML, you should probably use an HTML parsing tool to extract the contents of the `<body>` tag.

Comment: e.g. `xmllint --html --xpath '//body/node()' file.htm` will probably get you what you want.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [bash: get content between a pair of HTML tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21015587/bash-get-content-between-a-pair-of-html-tags)

Comment: *"using `sed` to search for `<body>` and delete all lines before this line including the `<body>` line"* -- this requirement is not well defined. The opening tag of the `body` element (i.e. `<body>`) is allowed to have attributes (`<body class="foo">` etc). Searching for `<body>` might fail finding it. Also, there is no guarantee that it is alone on the line. Removing the entire line might be too much. This is actually not a job for `sed` and you didn't define it correctly because you are thinking of it in `sed` terms (i.e. process the file line by line).

Answer (score 1):

as says @Tom Fenech :

```
xmllint --html --xpath '//body/node()' index.htm* > index-temp.html
```

- `<body> and <BODY>` are targeted
- `*.html?(l)` for only htm/html but with extglob active (debian default)

with the details of @tripleee:

```
find "$input" -type f -iregex '.*\.html?' \
  -exec sh -c 'for f; do
      xmllint --html --xpath "//body/node() "$f" >"${f%.htm*}"-temp.html;
    done' _ {} +
```

Comment: Or `find ... -exec sh -c 'for f; do xmllint --html --xpath "//body/node() "$f" >"${f%.htm*}"-temp.html; done' _ {} +`

Comment: ... Though `*.htm?` matches `html` and `htmq` but not just `htm`; and without quotes, your shell will expand the match if there are matching files in the current directory. You want `-iregex '.*\.html?'` or something like that, with quotes.

Comment: I have to use sed and not use xmllint

Answer (score 0):

For a single file, the sed command would be:

```
sed '1,/<body>/d;/<\/body>/,/$/d' index.html > index-temp.html
```

The syntax is

```
sed 'ROWa,ROWz d'
```

where ROWa is the linenumber to start, ROWz where to end, inclusive, counting from 1. The $ can be used for LASTLINE.

You can use patterns too:

```
sed '/PATa/,/PATz/ d'
```

From pattern PATa until pattern PATz. And pattern/lines can be mixed.

Now for the find-part:

```
find "$input" -type f -name "*.htm*" -exec sed -i.temp '0,/<body>/d;/<\/body>/,/$/d' {} ";"
```

would change the htm(l)-file, but create a backup (like index.html.temp) from the original.

Maybe that's even more convenient to you. Else you have to rename all those files, which would require another script, since sed and find themselve know no redirection, so it would require some shell invocation with basename, which would be an alternative way to go:

```
#/bin/bash
#
# justbody.sh
#
infile=$1
outfile="$(basename $infile .htm)-temp.htm"
sed '0,/<body>/d;/<\/body>/,/$/d' $infile > $outfile
```

and now invocation by:

```
find "$input" -type f -name "*.htm" -exec ./justbody.sh {} ";"
```

Comment: The `0,` pattern is a GNU `sed` extension I believe.

Comment: @tripleee: Well, I explain that it counts from 1 but write '0' (which silently worked) but I corrected it.

Comment: What if `<body class="foo">`? And what if `<html><head><title>etc</title></head><body></body></html>`, everything on a single line? Editing HTML is definitely not a job for `sed`.

Comment: @axiac: `echo "<html><head><title>etc</title></head><body></body></html>" | sed '0,/<body>/d;/<\/body>/,/$/d'` returns nothing, according to the requirements: **and delete all lines before this line including the <body> line** and **and deleting all the lines after that including <body> line**. What did you find out, which violates these requirements or what definition of **line** do you use? And the question was about `using sed to search for <body>`, not to search for a body-tag. If you have different requirements, ask your own question, please.

Comment: @axiac: I see that you asked ItInNeed for clarification about that question too, which is the right way to go. But as long as you aren't the producer of said html-file and know better about the requirements, your conclusions are premature. Without confirmation, that the idea to search line wise and only literally for `<body>` is too narrow, you shouldn't criticise the answers.

Comment: This is suppose that i have one file and i know the line of the body. What i need is to have multiple files located under folder  and subfolders as well as different HTML and HTM files that does not have the same body location. Is there any sed command that erase all before <body> and all after </body>?

Comment: @ItInNeed: No, it's not. The 2nd last code block is a script, called by the last code line, which is exactly for that purpose. It could be adopted to absolute line numbers, but here only the first and last line are absolute, the open/close-body-tags are searched for for each file. If the name varies between htm and html and maybe HTM(L), there have to be some adjustments to be made, or a second pair of script/command been made. The find command can work with '-iname "*.htm*", but the script has to evaluate the concrete extension for the outfile - that's one if-statement or a case statement.

Comment: The command `sed '1,/<body>/d; /<\/body>/,/$/d'` deletes from line 1 to the body-tag and from the end-body-tag to the end of file.

Comment: execuse me but im a Little bit newbie. do you mean that i have to create two scripts? the first one is to call find "$input" -type f -name "*.htm" -exec ./justbody.sh {} ";" and then Another script "justbody.sh?

Comment: Well, that's ok. Read the text and try to understand what it says. Make experiments, to prove to yourself, that you understood what was new for you. Make experimental data, to try the examples. If you don't get over some hurdle, feel free to ask.

Comment: i acutally ran some test for just this statement find "$input" -type f -name "*.htm*" -exec sed -i.temp '0,/<body>/d;/<\/body>/,/$/d' {} ";"  for a test file and that have <body style="background-color:Yellow;"> at the beginning and </body> at the end and the result was that all the content were deleted after the perfoming the script

Comment: Sed scans lines for text patterns. It knows nothing about xml or html or any other syntax. `<body>` doesn't match `<body style=...>`. You may try  `<body[^>]*>` which means 'the word "body" after the "<" sign, followed by an arbitrary number of not ">" signs and finally a ">" sign. You need to read about regular expressions and take a sed tutorial, it is a mighty technique and regexes are universally very useful, but without investing time you don't get far.

Comment: With  `find ... -name "*.htm*" -exec grep "<body" {} ";"` you can get an overview, how the lines look, which match "<body" somehow, for example it is critical, that the tag always ends in the same line and nothing, which you like to preserve, follows in the same line - else xmllint and so on might be the better tool for the job.